# What encoding used when receive Ktor response as bytes

Tags: kotlin, serialization, encoding, deserialization, ktor

Ktor has a `receive` method with generic. How it is transformed to ByteArray if I call REST API and receive response body as ByteArray?

I have a problem because I need to receive request body as ByteArray, then deserialize it to list of objects, then filter it with some condition, and then serialize it to ByteArray back. How I can do this? I try to find such information, but couldn't.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually the opposite than you think. Network works on stream of bytes, so `ByteArray` is "closer" to the original data than anything else, it does not use any encoding or additional processing. When you receive a `String` then you use some encoding to decode the data from the byte stream.

The easiest would be to receive `String` instead of `ByteArray`. If you can't do this then you have to either look into the HTTP headers returned by the server or consult the documentation of this REST API to determine what encoding does it use. It is very probable that it always returns the data in `UTF-8`.